# Serving lua pages in apache windows

Tags: apache, lua, cgilua

I have been using php for CGI scripting for some time now and recently got interested in lua.

I installed the latest version of luarocks(2.1.2) and the bundled version of lua(5.1.4). I wanted to start from the basics and hence installed cgilua(5.1.4-2) and all its dependencies using "luarocks install cgilua".

I am able to run simple lua scripts using the shebang line to point to my lua interpreter but when i use it to point to the cgi launcher "`cgilua.cgi.exe`" to run `.lp` files it just won't work. I edited my `httpd` configuration file to allow cgi execution in my `htdocs` and `cgi-bin` directory and used the cgi-script handler for `.lp` pages. I am trying to run the `login.lp` example in the cgilua `examples` directory. I even added the line `"Content-type:text/html"` to no avail. Executing the `cgilua.cgi.exe` file from the command line without arguments just closes the application with the message *"cgilua.cgi.exe" stopped working"*.

Could anyone tell me what am I missing? Maybe the launcher is supposed to be used in a different way?

I don't suppose permissions have a part to play in this as in windows all users have at least read and execute permissions.

The url I'm trying to access is `http://localhost/login.lp`. My apache error log shows `"Premature end of script headers: login.lp"` with a 500 internal server error and the same thing if I access `http://localhost/cgilua.cgi.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your requirements are, but perhaps it will be easier to simply use apache's mod_lua.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_lua.html